# xarch=v9a is deprecated, use -m64 -xarch=sparcvis instead

Tags: architecture, openssl, solaris, deprecation-warning

I am compiling `Openssl` on Solaris 11.1, but it gives error

> cc: Warning: -xarch=v8plus is deprecated, use -m32 -xarch=sparc
>   instead.

So How to use `-m32 -xarch=sparc` instead `-xarch=v8plus` on Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Solaris Studio C compiler, the man page is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-2676/cc.1.html).

Also assuming your problem is getting the Openssl compilation to use `-m32 -xarch=sparc` instead of `-xarch=v8plus`, there are configuration files (IIRC under the `Configurations` directory in the Openssl source) that contain the compilation flags.  If the warning bothers you, you can change the compilation flags in the configuration file(s) and rerun the Openssl configuration command(s) per the Openssl documentation.

Even easier since it's just a warning about a compiler option that **may** go away in a **future** compiler release is to not worry about it.

Comment: There is no "Configuration" directory in Openssl source. [Source Binaries](https://www.openssl.org/source/). These warnings prevents me from generating _libcrypto.so_ files

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there are still others wondering about this issue.
To add to Andrew Henle's answer (since I still can't add a comment due low reputation(?)).

The Configuration file he mentions is the `Configurations/10-main.conf` file.

You can find the section

```
#### SPARC Solaris with Sun C setups
...
"solaris-sparcv9-cc" => {
        inherit_from     => [ "solaris-sparcv7-cc", asm("sparcv9_asm") ],
        cflags           => add_before("-xarch=v8plus"),
    }
...
```

Just edit the arguments in `add_before` to `-m32 -xarch=sparc` or the recommended arguments displayed in you warning log.

EDIT: I know this is a hack but I currently don't see where to address this warning logs. I'm not an expert on this so if anyone can correct me, please do so.